# Method to find "if map data is available or not"

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using Arcgis javascript api 3.2. I use the mapservice,

```
 https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer.
```

I realized that map data is not available when the scale(slider) is zoomed to the fullest at certain places on the map. Is there a method to find out if map data is available or not? Could you please share the steps in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to the rest service url of the map service in a browser, you can see information about the service, including the level of detail for the service.  This paticular service has 20 levels of detail, with information about the scale and resolution of each level.

You can use this sample:

```
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/map_customtilelevels
```

to set the level of details that are visible for your mapping application.